# My screen is partially broken. How can I adjust the viewable space using xrandr or any similar tool?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, screen, display-resolution, xrandr

My secondary monitor is partially broken in the top 1/3 of the screen so I want to add blackbars and have something like in the picture below.
The top part it's how everything is now. The bottom part is what I want to achieve. The resolutions listed there are the maximum for each screen.

This is the xrandr output for the second screen:

```
VGA1 connected 1920x1080+1366+12 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 890mm x 500mm
1920x1080     60.00*+
1600x1200     60.00  
1680x1050     59.95  
1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
1440x900      74.98    59.89  
1280x960      60.00  
1360x768      60.02  
1280x800      59.81  
1152x864      75.00  
1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
832x624       74.55  
800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32  
640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00  
720x400       70.08
```

[image: Schematic]

All help is appreciated :)

Comment: Do yourself a favor and obtain a new one.

Comment: Give me the money and I'd gladly buy a new one :)